# Calling a C# async method from Python

Tags: python, c#, dll, async-await

I have a small piece of code, in C#, that is creating a MS Graph API client. In VS code, its working as expected, now in order to consume this code from Python I have created a DLL and using this DLL in Python.

This is the C# code snippet-

```
  public static async Task<string> TestMethod()
    {

        //some variable defination
        Console.WriteLine("Before creation of client");
        //method call to get the token 
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient_Test = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside sync meethod ");
           
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            Console.WriteLine("out sync meethod ");

        })
        );
        Console.WriteLine("before message ");
        var message = new Message
        {
          //some message defination
        };


        Console.WriteLine("before await 2 ");

        await graphServiceClient_Test.Me
                  .SendMail(message, false)
                  .Request()
                  .PostAsync();

        return "Success";

    }
```

and this is how I am calling this code from Python- *sendMail is the class*

```
newfeature = asyncio.run(sendMail.TestMethod())
```

and this is how my python console look like-

```
Before creation of client
before message 
before await 2 
inside sync meethod 
out sync meethod 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/DLLImportTest/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    newfeature = asyncio.run(sendMail.TestMethod())
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 37, in run
    raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <System.Threading.Tasks.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] object at 0x000001EA0185EEC8>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code is breaking when I am using the client to send the email out. I am totally new to Python and not sure where i am going wrong. May be there is a different way to call the "awaited" module ? Any help is appreciated.